# Plus sign ( + ) in a rewrite rule (.HTACCESS on Linux Server)

Tags: rewrite

i've this snippet, but it doesn't works. Obviously is that plus sign + tha must be escape ?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=t+max$
RewriteRule ^it/cerca$ http://www.wrs.sm/it/cerca?orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=tmax? [R=301,L]
```

i want to redirect this url

```
http://www.wrs.sm/it/cerca?orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=t+max
```

to this

```
http://www.wrs.sm/it/cerca?orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=tmax
```

Thanks ;)

I found the solution, the correct rules are:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=t\+max$
RewriteRule ^it/cerca$ http://www.wrs.sm/it/cerca?orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=tmax [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please describe what do you want to do instead something that does not work.

Comment: yea you're right, i'll edit main topic ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/it/cerca$
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=t+max
            RewriteRule (.*) http://www.wrs.sm/it/cerca?orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=tmax [R,L]
```

This may be a good starting point.

Comment: ...why, exactly ? How is it different from his RewriteCond/Rule combination ?

Comment: it doesn't works :-/ doesn't give an error, simply remain same url

Comment: @adaptr I copied from a working example from a website operated by me. (Yeah, maybe + needs escaping like the asker said later...)